# Transition from one wallet to another

Tags: transactions

I made a transition from one blockchain to coinbase without using MEMO, Will I lose the funds?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this guide (https://medium.com/stellar-community/help-i-forgot-my-stellar-memo-d62b3cc9c2f7) and reach out to the Coinbase support team.

Comment: Please do not post answers that consist just of links.  The link may become dead and the answer becomes invalid.  Link-only answers are liable to be deleted.